# Set the position of a text or an image in a pdf using itextsharp(C#/asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have added an image and some text in the pdf using `iTextSharp`.  However, I would like to position my image and text at specific position in the pdf. How do I do it?

So far I tried,

```
img.SetAbsolutePosition(10000f,10000f);
```

But it is not working.
Here is my complete code for generating the pdf,

```
 private void generatepdf(byte[] byteImage)
  {


    //byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    string text1= "Some Text";
    iTextSharp.text.Image image =   iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(byteImage);
    image.ScalePercent(0.3f * 100);
    string logopath = Server.MapPath("~/images/img1.png");
    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(logopath);
    img.SetAbsolutePosition(1000f,1000f);
    img.ScaleAbsolute(1500f, 0f);
    img.ScalePercent(0.5f*100);
    Paragraph ShopName = new Paragraph(text1);
    Paragraph id = "Some Text";

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 188f, 88f, 5f, 10f);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(img);
        document.Add(ShopName);
        document.Add(image);
        document.Add(id);
        document.Close();
        byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=QRCode.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you tried `img.SetAbsolutePosition(10000f,10000f);` then your image is way out of the visible area of the PDF. You are creating your `Document` like this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 188f, 88f, 5f, 10f);
```

This means that the size of the page is 595 x 842 user units. Using `x = 10000` and `y = 10000` doesn't fit inside a rectangle of 595 x 842.

Please try:

```
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
```

When you use these coordinates, the lower-left corner of the image will coincide with the lower-left corner of the page.

Please consult the official iText documentation and search for [coordinate system](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/coordinate-system). See for instance:

- [How should I interpret the coordinates of a rectangle in PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-should-i-interpret-coordinates-rectangle-pdf)
- [Where is the origin (x,y) of a PDF page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/where-origin-xy-pdf-page)
- ...

This will help you find how to define the coordinates for the `SetAbsolutePosition()` method.

**Update:**

You are also asking about adding text at absolute positions. Here we have to make the distinction between a single line of text and a block of text. See also the section [Absolute positioning of text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/absolute-positioning-text) on the official web site.

*A single line of text:*

See for instance [How to position text relative to page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-position-text-relative-page) and you'll find the `showTextAligned()` method:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
    new Phrase("Some text"), 100, 100, 0);
```

Please make sure that you read other examples to so that you discover what the `canvas` object is about.

*A block of text:*

Take a look at [How to add text inside a rectangle?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-inside-rectangle)

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("This is the text added in the rectangle"));
ct.Go();
```

Please take a look at the full example to find out what `cb` and `rect` are about.

Comment: Thanks,That worked well for an image, how about the text?How can I do the same for some text?

Comment: After I read description of iText I undestood this answer and successfully used ColumnText.showTextAligned in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, BUT in case anyone comes throught the pain of setting an image with a certain layout.
At least from my experience it's a good idea to set the position by using tables.

```
 PdfPTable tableSignature = new PdfPTable(4);
        tableSignature.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
        tableSignature.DefaultCell.BorderColor = Color.WHITE;
        tableSignature.WidthPercentage = 90;

        var encodedImage = signatureString.Split(',')[1];

        var bytesSignature = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedImage);
        iTextSharp.text.Image imageSignature = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bytesSignature);
        imageSignature.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK;
        // this size seems right but, we need to check in more samples.
        imageSignature.ScaleToFit(120, 60);

        imageSignature.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_BOTTOM;

        PdfPCell cellSignature = new PdfPCell(imageSignature);
        cellSignature.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_TOP;
        cellSignature.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE;
        tableSignature.AddCell(cellSignature);
        tableSignature.AddCell("       ");
        tableSignature.AddCell("       ");

        PdfPCell cellDateSignatureText = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dateFilledInDocument));

        ((Chunk)(cellDateSignatureText.Phrase[0])).Font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(((Chunk)(cellDateSignatureText.Phrase[0])).Font.Family, 12f);
        cellDateSignatureText.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE;
        cellDateSignatureText.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        cellDateSignatureText.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        cellDateSignatureText.BorderWidthBottom = 1;
        cellDateSignatureText.BorderColorBottom = Color.BLACK;
        tableSignature.AddCell(cellDateSignatureText);

        PdfPCell signatureCellText = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Signature"));

        ((Chunk)(signatureCellText .Phrase[0])).Font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(((Chunk)(signatureCellText .Phrase[0])).Font.Family, 12f);
        signatureCellText .BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE;
        signatureCellText .HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_BOTTOM;

        tableSignature.AddCell(signatureCellText);
        tableSignature.AddCell("       ");
        tableSignature.AddCell("       ");

        tableSignature.AddCell("Date");

        document.Add(tableSignature);
```

For example in the code above we inserted a signature and a date at the end of a pdf.

Hope this works for someone out there.