# Replace Text into an existing PDF document in a specific positions in JavaScript & Asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation

I have an existing 20-page pdf file.
I need to extract data from our database and incorporate it into a pdf document for specific positions. I did research on Google but I did not find anything. Any NuGet packages or any Java script packages?

Comment: Text *replacement* may be non-trivial. Have you checked whether the used fonts allow text extraction and - if they are embedded - they are embedded with enough glyphs?

Comment: You can easily do it through iText7 or older version itextsharp.
[Set Position of text or image in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458108/set-the-position-of-a-text-or-an-image-in-a-pdf-using-itextsharpc-asp-net)